# WooCommerce Points and Rewards - Move render_product_message

Tags: php, plugins, woocommerce

I'm using the WooCommerce Points and Rewards plugin.

By default, the single product message (Earn up to x Points.) appears immediately after product excerpt. However, I want change it.

I already tried a lot of things, but without success... but I think that I'm close to the right answer.

I hope that someone can give me a help.

```
function test() {
   global $wc_points_rewards;
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', array($wc_points_rewards->product, 'render_product_message' ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'test', 5 );
```

The class that adds the "render_product_message" is WC_Points_Rewards_Product that is initialized on WC_Points_Rewards.

WC_Points_Rewards_Product (i'm only posting the related method)

```
 public function __construct()
 {
     // add single product message immediately after product excerpt
     add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', array($this, 'render_product_message'));
 }
```

WC_Points_Rewards (i'm only posting the related method).
The includes method is called on __construct method of this class.

```
private function includes()
{
    // product class
    require('includes/class-wc-points-rewards-product.php');
    $this->product = new WC_Points_Rewards_Product();
}
```

Comment: "I already tried a lot of things, but without success..." -- what kinds of things, and why were they not successful?

Comment: In my comment is an example of what I tried added to my functions.php. I also tried used $wc_points_rewards instead of $wc_point_rewars->product. But I think that as I posted is the correct because the class is $wc_point_rewars->product and not $wc_point_rewars.

Comment: Can you show us the `add_action()` that adds the `render_product_message` function? Also, what class is this `add_action` from and how do we access the instance of this class? Please edit the question to add the requested information.

Comment: I already changed the post and add more code and information.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 add_action( 'init', 'remove_points');
 function remove_points()
 {
     global $wc_points_rewards;
     remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button',  [ $wc_points_rewards->product, 'render_product_message' ], 15 );
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You are better off renaming the fields in the class-wc-points-rewards-product.php file to show "after" or "before" an element. Sure, you'll have to rename every time there's an update but writing a hook might mess something up.